# Visual Studio SetUp Project -- How to package .rpt files for my application to be installed along with the main app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, installation, setup-project

I am new to Crystal reports installing. I have an application that contains Crystal reports *rpt files. I have a setUp project that correctly builds *.msi file that install the dlls and exe files for my application but currently does not package the *.rpt files as well. How do I set this up to copy the  *.rpt files and copy them to a folder local to the install? I would like to even specify the particular path on the local machine the  *.rpt files should be copied to. How do I do this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What installer are you using... Micorsoft's built in publish/deployment, third party like WISE or something else.  If your using built in publish you simply need to click on the application files button on the publish page and set them to include.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio set up project to build an msi which I then run on the client machine. Note, this is not a web application but a windows app.

Comment: Probably the best bet would be to set all the *.rpt files as "Content" files, and then during your "Add Project" bits in the setup project of your solution, add the project that contains the *.rpt files and set the output type you are including to be "Content".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem in my project setup project.

a) Open your project setup Project in Visual Studio. 
b) Right click the project, and select View > File System
c) Right click the Application Folder (in left panel of the File System window, right under File System on Target Machine node in menu), and select Add> Folder
d) Add the name of the Folder where you want your reports to be installed on the client machine, in my case, my folder was name REPORTS
e) Add copy of your *.rpt files from your application to the folder you just created in your set up project
f) Build your setup project, and when installed, a reports folder will be created and the copy of your report files will be included in that folder.